# python datetime.date not match SQL date

Tags: python, datetime, pyodbc, netezza

I have some data, I want to insert into table in netezza:

```
import pyodbc
data=[['GZ', datetime.date(2017, 2, 8), 19.7, 10.7, 0, '1级'], 
      ['GZ', datetime.date(2017, 2, 9), 16.3, 9.7, -1, '微风'], 
      ['GZ', datetime.date(2017, 2, 10), 16.0, 10.0, -1, '微风']]
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL}; SERVER=**;DATABASE=weather; UID=**; PASSWORD=**;")
cur = conn.cursor()
for i in data:
   cur.execute("""
         insert into WEATHER_INFO(location,weather_date,high_tempature,low_tempature,weather,wind)
         values(\'%s\',%s,%s,%s,%s,\'%s\')
         """ % (i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5]))
   conn.commit()
cur.execute('select * from WEATHER_INFO')
print(cur.fetchall())
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I get some ERROR:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] ERROR:  Attribute 'WEATHER_DATE' is of type 'DATE' 
but expression is of type 'INT4'\n\tYou will need to rewrite or cast the expression (46) 
(SQLExecDirectW)")
```

this is table structure:

```
create table weather(
 location varchar(20),
 weather_date date,
 high_tempature float(4,1),
 low_temputare float(4,1),
 weather int(11),
 wind varchar(20)
);
```

I know the python datime.date should match SQL date. I don't get the answer that I want through search the stackoverflow. So how I should slove this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the string formatting operator `%` to create *dynamic SQL* and those SQL statements are malformed. If we print out the actual statements that you are trying to execute they look like

```sql
insert into WEATHER_INFO(location,weather_date,high_tempature,low_tempature,weather,wind)
values('GZ',2017-02-08,19.7,10.7,0,'1级')
```

Notice that the date value is inserted as `2017-02-08` with no delimiters so it is being interpreted as an integer expression.

What you need to do is use a proper *parameterized query*:

```python
sql = """\
insert into WEATHER_INFO(location,weather_date,high_tempature,low_tempature,weather,wind)
values(?,?,?,?,?,?)
"""
for i in data:
    cur.execute(sql, i)
    conn.commit()
```

or maybe just

```python
sql = """\
insert into WEATHER_INFO(location,weather_date,high_tempature,low_tempature,weather,wind)
values(?,?,?,?,?,?)
"""
cur.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```